# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to access the databse using EF Core 5.0 on an ASP.NET Core project. For the first migration, I overrode the `OnConfiguring()` method on the DBContext and updated the database successfully.

For the second migration, I decided to use the dependency injection in ASP.NET Core following the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services). Here are the changes I made.

1. Added `services.AddDbContext` in my `Startup.cs`.
2. Removed the `OnConfiguring()` method from `DBContext`.

After running `dotnet ef migrations add Posts`, I get following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: 
Unable to create an object of type 'BlogContext'. 
For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

If I add the --verbose flag, I get this output:

```
Build started...
dotnet build blog/app/app.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.50
Build succeeded.

Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'app'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'BlogContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'BlogContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[app.Data.BlogContext]' while attempting to activate 'app.Data.BlogContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   
Unable to create an object of type 'BlogContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

However, the code works as expected when I run the web application, as in the `BlogContext` is created and injected into my classes by the DI layer, and I can access the database.

Hence, I am guessing the DI layer is not running as expected when running the `dotnet ef migrations add` command.

Here's my code.

```
// Program.cs

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                                        .UseSerilog()
                                        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                                        {
                                            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                                        });

        IHost host = builder.Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}

// BlogContext

using app.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace app.Data
{
    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public BlogContext(DbContextOptions<BlogContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
}

// Startup.cs

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
         Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public string ConnectionString => Configuration.GetConnectionString("Blog");

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(opt => { opt.UseSqlite(ConnectionString); });
    }
}
```

Both the `Startup` and `BlogContext` live in the same project.

Comment: How about your app entry point (`Program` class) - is it following the pattern described here [Design-time DbContext Creation - From application services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services)? If yes, may be there is another exception or code not shown here which is causing it. Posting the full verbose output might help identifying the cause.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, yes, I am following same pattern in the `Program` class. I have updated my question to include the `Program.cs` file and the complete verbose output. Thanks!

Comment: You're not following the recommended pattern. Note how the example linked by @IvanStoev shows how EF Core uses the `Program.CreateHostBuilder` method that's missing from your code.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed the error in the verbose output. `No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.` I will refactor my code to use the original pattern. Thank you @Ivan and Kirk.

Comment: I just tested this and it works as expected. If any of you can post this as an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise, I can post it myself.

Comment: Yup, they are trying to run that method directly if exists as described in the documetation : *"The tools first try to obtain the service provider by invoking Program.CreateHostBuilder()..."*. And verbose output show that as well. Happy coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan and Kirk's comments above and reading the entire verbose output, I figured out the problem. Turned out I was not following the correct pattern in `Program.cs`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services),

`The tools first try to obtain the service provider by invoking Program.CreateHostBuilder(), calling Build(), then accessing the Services property.`

I had refactored the original `Program.cs` by moving `CreateHostBuilder()` inside `main()`, which broke the ef-core migration.

After modifying the `Program.cs` to following it works as expected.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In my experience, better to create a class (in the same project as the context) that implements IDesignTimeDbContextFactory - as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory). That way, there's not guessing as to which code will get used when using the design time tools such as update-database

Comment: This worked for me on .Net 6

Comment: This was my problem, I have an Api project, a Data project where my context is, and a Domain project with my models. The VS Mac tools still don't work but the command line `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` now works using this method.

Comment: There's also a simple example here that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196547/visual-studio-2022-net-6-scaffolding-doesnt-work-when-dbcontext-is-in-a-separa

Essentially, you create a design time ApplicationDbContext that the scaffolder uses to generate the code.