# visual studio 2022 .NET 6 Scaffolding doesn't work when DbContext is in a separate project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm setting up my first .NET 6 MVC site, and am falling at the first hurdle.

I have 3 projects in the solution.
Domain: contains the Entities
Infrastructure: has the applications DB context
WebUi: contains the web interface

adding migrations and updating the database works fine, but when I try to scaffold a controller, it errors with:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions’ While attempting to activate

Then names the DbContext in other class library project.

I've found others that have had similar issues a few months back, but no-one had any solutions other then bringing everything into the same project.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: are you able to fire `Add-Migration` command on `Infrastructure` solution?

Comment: Did you register the DbContext with the service provider in Startup.cs?

Comment: @ElyasEsna: yes adding migrations and updating the database works fine.

Comment: @funatparties .NET6 doesn't have a startup, but I have added the context to the program.cs
The actual DB plumbing works (migrations, updates, adding Identity users). It's just an issue when trying to scaffold a controller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally found something that worked for me:
You can create a dbcontext factory class in same folder with your ApplicationDbContext class. This factory class creates ApplicationDbContext at design time and scaffolding runs correctly

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EcommerceDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
}
```

Credit goes to : https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1765#issuecomment-1058674843

Comment: wow, WHAT A PAING IN THE A!!!   so much time searching for this solution, thanks!  Problem was that error is used in so many other places, it was really difficult to find this solution due to that, but this finally worked for me.

Comment: works for me, 
i had encountered the error when i was making a point to our team that project templates and scaffolding will save us time.
thanks

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, thank you.  This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the correct packages in the same project as the context. You will need the following.

> microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.entityframeworkcore
> microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver

Also make sure you are using a hard coded options builder connection in your context rather than the name parameter like below. Just remember to change it back before publishing your changes.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer
            //("Name=ConnectionStrings:[AppSettingsConnectionName]");
            // Use this OB to scaffold
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer
            (@"Data Source=[Server];Initial Catalog=[DBName];");
        }
    }
```